# How to reload the youtube video in my HTML every time the page is run?

Tags: javascript, html, reload, src

I have a youtube video embedded, just like this:

```
<object width="640" height="360">
        <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></embed>
</object>
```

Then I am replacing its src attribute using JS:

```
function replaceSrc()
    {

        document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].src = "new_link";
    }
if (window.addEventListener){
         window.addEventListener('load', replaceSrc, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', replaceSrc);
    }
```

The function above will set a new `src` attribute, but it wont play a youtube video according to the new link. I need to make a reload of the youtube video in HTML with a newly set `src` attribute. Any suggestions? No YouTube API.

Comment: How about remove this DOM and then add the new DOM with that url as src attribute?

Comment: something like this? var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0];
        copy = elem.cloneNode();
    copy.src = "new_link";
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, elem); I have tried, but does not work neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question, and I want to give it as a warning for those having the same issue in the future: the posisition of your JS function matters!!
I have implemented such code

```
<script>
function replaceSrcc() {

    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0];
        copy = elem.cloneNode();
    copy.src = "https://www.youtube.com/v/SKQeNnNT_Vg?version=3";
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, elem);
    } 


    if (window.addEventListener){
         window.addEventListener('load', replaceSrcc, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', replaceSrcc);
    }

</script>
```

Firstly, I put it into `<head>` tag, along with other JS functions defined for another stuff in my page. It did not work. Then, as a last option, I put it into `<body>` tag and now it works. Kind of crazy, however, it is a fact.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't pretty but you could add a generated number as a href-suffix.

http://youtube.com/VideoOfACat**?RandomVariable**

Gets you a refreshed version of the clip

Basically you can put whatever you want after the **?**, the browser still refreshes the link.
Simplest would perhaps be a global variable that get 1++ each reload.

Comment: dont understand completely, I already have one variable after ? mark, it is defining the version of the youtube player, version = 3 (https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3). Do you mean adding another ? behind that?

Comment: Yes, you can add how much junk as you want as long as it's a ? between. I'm guessing the The "Version=3" doesn't change and therefor the video isn't refreshed. 

So, generate a global variable with jQuery that is +1 every reload and attach it with a **?** and the end of the link, should do it :)

Trivia: If you use the same principle when watching a youtube-clip (on youtube) you can often dodge the ads :)